# Read changes from within a transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions

Whatever changes made to the MySQL database, are those changes readable within the same transaction? Or should I commit the transaction to read the changes?

I could easily test this. But putting a question in SO brings up a lot of good suggestions. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using InnoDB, the answer to your first question is generally yes, implying the answer to your second is generally no.

By default MySQL's InnoDB uses a technique called [consistent non-locking reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html):

> The query sees the changes made by
>   transactions that committed before
>   that point of time, and no changes
>   made by later or uncommitted
>   transactions. The exception to this
>   rule is that the query sees the
>   changes made by earlier statements
>   within the same transaction.

That being said, there's a lot of stuff to know about transactions.  You can change the [isolation level of a transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) in order to control the transaction results more thoroughly.

The chapter on the [InnoDB Transaction Model](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html) is a great place to start.

Comment: Thanks! The link about locks set by statements is very useful.